# Generating a 3D representation using a 2D picture using opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I don't know if the title explains what I'm trying to do, but after a few days with no sleep and searching the web I pretty much don't know how to do this.

I'm trying to take a point on a 2D image and find the depth of the rest of the points in the selected region relative to that point.

From all the internet search I've done, it seems that this is possible by a single 2D image but Stereoimages could be used to increase the accuracy of the triangulation.

Ultimately I am looking into doing this using stereovision but if anyone knows how to do it using a single image I also would appreciate it.

I am using OpenCV 249 in C++ vb12 (visual studio 2013).

any help is appreciated.

Comment: no, not possible with *1* image only. either use calibrated sterocameras, or 'bundle' multiple images from different viewpoints ( structure from motion)

Comment: Tha's what I thought at first. I'll look into calibrated stereo cameras

Comment: There's no way to display 2D images as 3D in a reallistic way  unless you are using stereo cameras or capture devices that have in-built depth sensors, such as  Kinect or [Creative Interactive Gesture Camera](http://click.intel.com/creative-interactive-gesture-camera-developer-kit.html).

Comment: Yea I realize that now. So now I am using stereocameras. I am trying to do this with the passive method (without use of any laser and/or IR sensors for depth perception) so two cameras would be my method of choice. Now that I know what to look for I have a better idea of where and how to search for it. Thank you guys very much :)

Comment: 'Just' using a stereo camera won't cut it. There is a very good reason why people add lasers / projectors / etc to a 3D aquisition setup; It's because the matching of two cameras is *hard*. This site http://mesh.brown.edu/byo3d/source.html gives an excellent writeup (and source!) of a structured light scanner.